# Callback not waiting for function to finish executing

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

I have a callback function that returns an object from the database. However, in my async.waterfall the function 'external' does not wait for the object to be fully loaded meaning it is undefined when passed in. This means my final error is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined`. What am I doing wrong?

```
function loadModelInstance (name, callback) {
  Model.findOne({ name: name }, function (_err, result) {
    if (result) {

      return callback(_err, result.content)
    } 
  })
}

function generatedNow (modelInstance) {
  generatedKeys = generatedKeys.concat(getAllMatches(generatedRegexp, modelInstance.replace(/(\n|\r)/g, '')));
}

async.waterfall(
    [
      function loadTemplate (wfaCallback) {
        loadModelInstance(name, function (_err, modelInstance) {
          wfaCallback(_err, modelInstance)
        })
      },

      function external (modelInstance, wfaCallback) {
        generatedNow(tracking, message, modelInstance, placeholders, function (err, updatedPlaceholders) {
        })
      },
    ],
    function (err) {
        // Node.js and JavaScript Rock!
    }
);
```

Comment: You are missing the `await` keyword.

Comment: But I'm not using async await :/ Could you explain further please? I thought the whole purpose about the callback function is that it would wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please provide more details. where are you calling "generateNow" function. i don't see function call for "generateNow".

Looks like you haven't used the parameter order properly. Below code should work.

```
async.waterfall(
  [
    function loadTemplate(wfaCallback) {
      loadModelInstance(name, function(_err, modelInstance) {
        wfaCallback(_err, modelInstance);
      });
    },

    function external(err, modelInstance, wfaCallback) {
      generatedNow(modelInstance, tracking, message, placeholders, function(
        err,
        updatedPlaceholders
      ) {});
    }
  ],
  function(err) {
    // Node.js and JavaScript Rock!
  }
);
```

Comment: I edited it. I'm not providing all of the assignment of the variables in this question as I want to keep it short.

Comment: Unfortunately.not. It's a really strange behaviour. I'm logging inside 'generatedNow' but I cannot see the logs even though the function gets executed..

Comment: I don't know if this is some weird asynchronous programming behaviour

Comment: I have edited my answer, could you please try again?

Comment: TypeError: modelInstance.replace is not a function

Comment: if I log inside external, they do not appear but the function generatedNow is executed ;/

Comment: Yes, the argument order was wrong. It seems to be working now...Thank you!